# Переход на другую страницу после отправки данных php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Есть простая форма:

```
<form class="callback__form" action="send.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="urname" placeholder="Ваше имя.." required>
            <input type="text" name="urtel" placeholder="Ваш телефон.." required>
            <input type="submit" id="send-post" value="Вызвать мастера">
</form>
```

Есть php скрипт для отправки:

```
<?php
$urname = $_POST['urname'];
$urtel = $_POST['urtel'];
$urname = htmlspecialchars($urname);
$urtel = htmlspecialchars($urtel);
$urname = urldecode($urname);
$urtel = urldecode($urtel);

mail("test@gmail.com", "Заявка", "Имя:".$urname.". Телефон: ".$urtel ,"From: test2@gmail.com \r\n");
if (mail("test@gmail.com", "Заявка", "Имя:".$urname.". Телефон: ".$urtel ,"From: test2@gmail.com \r\n"))

if ($mail == 1) {
    header("Location: /thanks.html");
}
?>
```

Данные с формы на почту приходят, однако переход на страницу благодарности (thanks.html) не происходит.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка. Спасибо!

Comment: У вас не существует переменной `$mail` в природе.

Comment: @Visman `if ($mail == 1) {
    header("Location: /thanks.html");`
В этом месте ошибка? Если не затруднит, укажите более развёрнуто.

Comment: Функция `mail()` и переменная `$mail` это совершенно разные вещи, между собой ни как не связанные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $urname = $_POST['urname'];
    $urtel = $_POST['urtel'];
    $urname = htmlspecialchars($urname);
    $urtel = htmlspecialchars($urtel);
    $urname = urldecode($urname);
    $urtel = urldecode($urtel); 


    if (mail("test@gmail.com", "Заявка", "Имя:".$urname.". Телефон: ".$urtel ,"From: test2@gmail.com \r\n")) {
        header("Location: /thanks.html");
    }
 ?>
```

---

```
<?php 
  if(@mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo "Отправлено";
  }else{
    echo "Не отправлено";
  } 
?>
```